# CSS percentage bar is taking 100% instead of 40%

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a percentage status bar using only CSS so I have:

```css
span.chart {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
span.chart span { 
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
span.chart span:before {
  content: "\00a0";
}
span.label {       
}
```

```html
<div class="meter">
  <span class="chart">
     <span style="width: 40%;"></span>
  </span>
  <span class="label">40%</span> 
</div>
```

The problem is that the Red bar is taking 40% instead of 100% even if the width is set to 40%.

What am I missing?

Comment: by default span is a inline element change span to block (`display:block`) for .chart it will work

Comment: Your title says "percentage bar is taking 100% instead of 40%". Your text says "the Red bar is taking 40% instead of 100%". So it's tricky to know what you want. The code appears to work ok.

Comment: It looks like it's because you are not setting a width for the outer container (`meter`), so when you set the width of span (40%), the outer container just expands/shrinks to fit its contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<span class="chart">` width is not configured and also it is `inline` element, make it as `inline-block`.

```css
span.chart {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
span.chart span { 
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
span.chart span:before {
  content: "\00a0";
}
span.label {       
}
```

```html
<div class="meter">
  <span class="chart">
     <span style="width: 40%;"></span>
  </span>
  <span class="label">40%</span> 
</div>
```

Comment: I was completely missing the width on chart ... of course ... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're after:

http://jsfiddle.net/okw8za4h/

You need to set a width for the outer container and the very first span. Otherwise, the *actual* progress indicator will always appear to be 100% because its parent elements are just adjusting their size to fit their contents.

```
<div class="meter">
  <span class="chart">
     <span style="width: 40%;"></span>
  </span>
  <span class="label">40%</span> 
</div>

div
{
    width: 256px;
}

span.chart {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
span.chart span { 
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
span.chart span:before {
  content: "\00a0";
}
span.label {       
}
```